# subnet ID from an inline virtual network resource

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am creating a virtual network using Terraform and the subnets are created within the virtual network resource block (instead of using its own resource block).

I am trying to associate some route tables to the subnets, however I'm not sure how to obtain the subnet resource ID when the subnets are created within virtual network, could someone help?

**main.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.24.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
    skip_provider_registration = true
    features {}
}

###########################
# RESOURCE GROUP CREATION #
###########################
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
    name = var.rg.name
    location = var.rg.location
}

############################
# VIRTUAL NETWORK CREATION #
############################
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
    name = var.vnet.name
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
    location = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
    address_space = var.vnet.address_space
    dns_servers = var.vnet.dns_servers

    subnet {
        name = var.vnet.subnet1_name
        address_prefix = var.vnet.subnet1_address_prefix
    }

    subnet {
        name = var.vnet.subnet2_name
        address_prefix = var.vnet.subnet2_address_prefix
    }

    subnet {
        name = var.vnet.subnet3_name
        address_prefix = var.vnet.subnet3_address_prefix
    }

    subnet {
        name = var.vnet.subnet4_name
        address_prefix = var.vnet.subnet4_address_prefix
    }

    subnet {
        name = var.vnet.subnet5_name
        address_prefix = var.vnet.subnet5_address_prefix
    }
}

########################
# ROUTE TABLE CREATION #
########################
resource "azurerm_route_table" "fslogix_rt" {
  name = var.rt.fslogix.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  disable_bgp_route_propagation = false
}

resource "azurerm_route_table" "back_office_rt" {
  name = var.rt.back_office.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  disable_bgp_route_propagation = false
}

resource "azurerm_route_table" "dev_dev_rt" {
  name = var.rt.dev_dev.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  disable_bgp_route_propagation = false
}

resource "azurerm_route_table" "dev_prod_rt" {
  name = var.rt.dev_prod.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  disable_bgp_route_propagation = false
}

resource "azurerm_route_table" "front_office_rt" {
  name = var.rt.front_office.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  disable_bgp_route_propagation = false
}

##################
# ROUTE CREATION #
##################
resource "azurerm_route" "fslogix_routes" {
  for_each = var.fslogix_routes
  name = each.value.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  route_table_name = azurerm_route_table.fslogix_rt.name
  address_prefix = each.value.address_prefix
  next_hop_type = each.value.next_hop_type
  next_hop_in_ip_address = each.value.next_hop_in_ip_address
}

resource "azurerm_route" "back_office_routes" {
  for_each = var.back_office_routes
  name = each.value.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  route_table_name = azurerm_route_table.back_office_rt.name
  address_prefix = each.value.address_prefix
  next_hop_type = each.value.next_hop_type
  next_hop_in_ip_address = each.value.next_hop_in_ip_address
}

resource "azurerm_route" "dev_dev_routes" {
  for_each = var.developer_dev_routes
  name = each.value.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  route_table_name = azurerm_route_table.dev_dev_rt.name
  address_prefix = each.value.address_prefix
  next_hop_type = each.value.next_hop_type
  next_hop_in_ip_address = each.value.next_hop_in_ip_address
}

resource "azurerm_route" "dev_prod_routes" {
  for_each = var.developer_prod_routes
  name = each.value.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  route_table_name = azurerm_route_table.dev_prod_rt.name
  address_prefix = each.value.address_prefix
  next_hop_type = each.value.next_hop_type
  next_hop_in_ip_address = each.value.next_hop_in_ip_address
}

resource "azurerm_route" "front_office_routes" {
  for_each = var.front_office_routes
  name = each.value.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  route_table_name = azurerm_route_table.front_office_rt.name
  address_prefix = each.value.address_prefix
  next_hop_type = each.value.next_hop_type
  next_hop_in_ip_address = each.value.next_hop_in_ip_address
}

###########################
# ROUTE TABLE ASSOICATION #
###########################
resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "fslogix_rta" {
  subnet_id = ???????????????????????????????????????
  route_table_id = azurerm_route_table.fslogix_rt.id
}
```

Comment: There is a subnet attribute: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_network#subnet.

Comment: @MarkoE, when I attempt to do that I get the following error │ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 171, in resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "fslogix_rta":
│  171:   subnet_id = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.subnet.id
│
│ Can't access attributes on a set of objects. Did you mean to access an attribute across all elements of the set?

Comment: Well, depends, do you want all the subnets attached to the same route table? If so, then probably using `for_each = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.subnet` or something similar would work. I don't know what the ouptut of that argument looks like so I can't answer.

Comment: @MarkoE At the moment I have 5 subnets and 5 route tables, with one route table being assigned to each subnet. So basically under route table association resource block, I need to know what to write so I select the correct subnet ID. I know I can do this by separating out the subnets into their own resource blocks, but trying to reduce the mount of code I need to write.

Comment: Sorry, I meant route table association.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the subnet_id with:

```
azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.subnet.*.id
```

You can get the first subnet_id with:

```
azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.subnet.*.id[0]
```

And the second subnet_id with:

```
azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.subnet.*.id[1]
```

And go on...

Hope this helps!